# I want to make a simple car game using while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

1--when we enter help following should appear:

start-to start the car
stop-to stop the car
quit-to exit

2--when we enter started message : car started should be shown

3--when entered stop: Car stopped should be displayed

4--when entered quit...should be exited through the loop

5--we cannot start car two times or more --message like car started already should be shown same with the stop
my code:

```
command=""
while True:
    command=input('>').lower()
    if command=='start':
        print("Car started")
    elif command=='stop':
         print("Car stopped")
    elif command=="help":
        print('''
start-to start the car
stop-to stop the car
quit-to exit
        ''')
    elif command=='quit':
        break
    else:
        print("I don't understand that")
```

I did these part but was unable to prevent the car from starting twice. Help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple flag `is_car_started` to record the status of whether the car is already started or not. When you start the car, set `is_car_started` to True. When you stop the car, set it to false.

```
command=""
is_car_started = False
while True:
    command=input('>').lower()
    if command=='start':
        if is_car_started == True:
            print("Car started already")
        else:
            is_car_started = True
            print("Car started")
    elif command=='stop':
         is_car_started = False
         print("Car stopped")
    elif command=="help":
        print('''
start-to start the car
stop-to stop the car
quit-to exit
        ''')
    elif command=='quit':
        break
    else:
        print("I don't understand that")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a boolean variable outside your while loop. Like `first_start = true`.

Then inside your while loop in the if statement where you check if `command=="start"` you can set `first_start` to false.

On the very top you can add an if-statement that prints your message when `first_start == false`.

The if-statement would look something like this:`if not first_start:...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of whether or not the car is started. You can also achieve a superior structure to your code with match/case (requires Python 3.10). For example:

```
started = False
while True:
    match input('Enter command: ').lower():
        case 'start':
            if started:
                print('Already started')
            else:
                print('Car started')
                started = True
        case 'stop':
            if started:
                print('Car stopped')
                started = False
            else:
                print('Car not started')
        case 'quit':
            print('Goodbye')
            break
        case 'help':
            print('''
                start-to start the car
                stop-to stop the car
                quit-to exit
                ''')
        case _:
            print("I don't understand that")
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue and this is how i resolved it
hope it helps...

```
    if is_car_started == True:
     print("car started already...")
    else:
     is_car_started = True
     print("car started... ready to go")
```